# What is the `.acks` key in Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My client `socket` has a property called `socket.acks`. This property continuously grows, and within a few minutes, there are over 5000 enteries in it.

They look something like this:

```
acks:
   { '11': [Function],
     '12': [Function],
     '13': [Function],
     '14': [Function],
     '15': [Function],
     '16': [Function],
     '17': [Function],
   }
```

**EDIT**

My server acts as a proxy to sending information between two clients.

**Server**

```
// Assume client1 is a reference to client1 socket, and client2 is for client2
socket.on('on_data_from_client1', function (data, cb) {
    // Here data and cb are sent to client2. 
    // I guess this is causing the .acks to be added since I am 
    // passing a function as last parameter to .emit.
    // But It is not me who should worry about the callback, but rather client2
    client2.emit('data_from_client1', data, cb);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the code, it's an object that contains unacknowledged messages.

Once a message has been acknowledged, it will be removed from this object, so I'm guessing that your client isn't acknowledging messages while the server is expecting acknowledgement to happen.

More information [here](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)).

**EDIT**

I've never used a similar setup so no idea if it's supposed to work at all (I foresee issues with unacknowledged messages when one of the clients disconnects, although I haven't looked close enough at the `socket.io` implementation to see if any pending acks will be cleaned up properly in that case).

The only possible solution I can think of right now is this (although it's functionally the same as yours):

```
socket.on('on_data_from_client1', function (data, cb) {
  client2.emit('data_from_client1', data, function(moreData) {
    return cb(moreData);
  });
});
```

Comment: Okay, what if my server is acting as a proxy between two clients? One client sends a message to the server (along with a callback function). This message and function are then sent to the other user. So in effect, I am emitting a function (which the documentation says is the callback), but I don't actually expect a callback.

Comment: @Kousha can you update your question with some code (how the client is sending the message and how the server is proxying it to another client)?